# Haskell greatest common divisor error?

Tags: haskell

I want to compute the greatest common divisor of two positive integer numbers in Haskell:

```
myGCD :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
myGCD a b
      | b == 0     = abs a
      | otherwise  = myGCD b (b `mod` a)
```

This should be a fairly simple algorithm. However, I find that I am getting some very strange results. I just can't seem to find an error in the above logic. Anything obvious stand out that would affect computing the greatest common divisor of `a` and `b`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost right! You mised up a call to `myGCD`. The correct code should read:

```
myGCD :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
myGCD a b
      | b == 0     = abs a
      | otherwise  = myGCD b (a `mod` b)
```

Reversing the order of `a` and `b` in that last line will give you some funky results!